# Remove hyperlinks from text but keep anchor text

Tags: c#, regex

I need to strip link tags from a body of text but keep the anchor text. for example:

```
<a href ="">AnchorText</a>
```

needs to become just:

```
AnchorText
```

I was considering using the following RegEx:

```
<(.{0}|/)(a|A).*?>
```

Is a RegEx the best way to go about this? If so, is the above RegEx pattern adequate? If RegEx isn't the way to go, what's a better solution? This needs to be done server side.

Comment: Are you trying to do this at design time? run time? Is this on a page you control or which you are downloading to a client?

Comment: It needs to happen server side on the fly. There are multiple pages that will be formatted and all exist on the server. Eventually they will be presented as a download.

Comment: Great, looks like you found a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex will do the job. You can write it a bit simpler as

```
</?(a|A).*?>
```

`/?` means 0 or 1 `/`

But its equivalent to your `(.{0}|/)`

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex):

```
string sampleHtml = "<a href =\"\">AnchorText</a>";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(sampleHtml);
string text = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText; //output: AnchorText
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a regex is the best way to accomplish this, and your pattern looks like it should work.

Comment: I heard somewhere that Regex's shouldn't be used for HTML - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 =D

Comment: Regex is not good for parsing html into tags, attributes and etc but in this case it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery replaceWith:

```
$('a').replaceWith(function()
{
    return $('<span/>').text($(this).text());
});
```

Assuming you are doing this on the client side.

Comment: I should have specified. I need to do this server side, otherwise I like your JQuery solution. Question edited/updated.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to do the same and found the following solution:

1. Export the text to CSV.
2. Open the file in Excel.
3. Run replace using <*> which will remove links and leave the anchor text.
4. Import the result again to overwrite existing content.